# How to label tmux tabs with the name of the file edited in vim?

Tags: vimrc, terminal, tmux

Whenever I open a tmux session in terminal, all of the tabs containing vim sessions are labelled `vim`.

My question is: How to configure it to label tmux tabs with the name of the edited file or something like `vim | test.cpp` used as the title of the tabs in question.

Comment: can this help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15124717/2558252 ?

Comment: thanks for this but can you please elaborate the process in a bit detail? Moreover the answer in not complete. The guy just gave an hint

Comment: as the question was answered (and IMHO correctly) could you accept it ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There you go :

```
autocmd BufReadPost,FileReadPost,BufNewFile,BufEnter * call system("tmux rename-window 'vim | " . expand("%:t") . "'")
```

Decomposing :

```
autocmd BufReadPost,FileReadPost,BufNewFile,BufEnter * call
```

On buffer read, file read or buffer new file event (see `:help autocmd-events`) execute the next command :

```
call system()
```

Call a system function and pass it the text :

```
"tmux rename-window 'vim | "
```

Rename the current window with a string starting with `vim |`

```
. expand("%:t")
```

Add to the string the filename (see [this article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_the_name_of_the_current_file) for the formatting and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842051/how-to-pass-argument-to-a-script-in-vim-system-call) for the expand insert)

```
. "'"
```

Add the final `'` to close the command.

After expanding it will look like (while editing the .vimrc file):

```
system("tmux rename-window 'vim | .vimrc'")
```

As @erthalion said in the comment, you can clean up when leaving vim with :

```
autocmd VimLeave * call system("tmux rename-window 'tmux'")
```

Comment: I think it will be nice to include `BufEnter` event into this list (to change label even when we switch between existing buffers), and something like this `autocmd VimLeave * call system("tmux rename-window 'tmux'")` for cleanup.

Answer (score 4):

To restore the default tmux naming scheme when quitting vim you can also do:

```
autocmd VimLeave * call system("tmux setw automatic-rename")
```

Comment: This is used in unison with the other answer provides the best solution. I have seen the tmux rename-window snippet all over, but this is the first time someone pointed out the automatic-rename tmux window option. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I put in my vimrc thanks to the answer by @raphael

I also install the [tmux-plugins/vim-tmux-focus-events](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/vim-tmux-focus-events) plugin for the FocusGained and FocusLost events.

```
augroup tmux
  autocmd!
  if exists('$TMUX')
    autocmd BufReadPost,FileReadPost,BufNewFile,FocusGained * call system("tmux rename-window " . expand("%:t"))
    autocmd VimLeave,FocusLost * call system("tmux set-window-option automatic-rename")
  endif
augroup END
```

Answer (score 0):

To add something more to other's answers, I've added some vimscript to restore the previous tmux window name instead of the automatic rename:

```
if exists('$TMUX')
  let windowName = system("tmux display-message -p '#W'")
  autocmd BufReadPost,FileReadPost,BufNewFile,BufEnter * call system("tmux rename-window 'vim(" . expand("%:t") . ")'")
  autocmd VimLeave * call system("tmux rename-window " . windowName)
endif
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!